# Flutter Page don't scroll

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a problem, when I want to scroll on the screen, the app doesn't scroll. What am I missing?

This is my
[code](https://gist.github.com/cristianfb1989/4e1858ecd868abefd7b0f77b4cf4da5b)

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('Second Page'),
  ),
  body: Center(
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .7,
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: itemsDishes.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return itemsDishes[index];
                },
              )),
          Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .9,
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: itemsDrinks.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return itemsDrinks[index];
                },
              )),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

As you can see, the column is nested within a SingleChildScrollView

[image]

Comment: Its scrolling, check this https://dartpad.dev/b6409e10de32b280b8938aa75364fa7b

Comment: @Robin check what? https://i.imgur.com/fi4aHgp.gifv

Comment: The link i mentioned above. Go that link.

Comment: you're using nested scroll widgets that are causing the issue. set shrinkWrap to true on each listview

Comment: well... it is scrolling, but you have 2 ListViews inside a ScrollView. The overflow you're seeing is from the first ListView. What you're looking for is a NestedScrollView. And, BTW, having 2 vertical ListViews on a vertical ScrollView is a bad UX.

Comment: Thank you all for the advices!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `Container`s wrapping your `ListView`s and set `shrinkWrap` as well as `physics` properties.

```
ListView.builder(
  shrinkWrap: true,
  physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
  itemCount: itemsDishes.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return itemsDishes[index];
  },
),
ListView.builder(
  shrinkWrap: true,
  physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
  itemCount: itemsDrinks.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return itemsDrinks[index];
  },
)
```

Comment: A `ListView` that never scrolls is essentially just an expensive `Column`.

Comment: I agree. For me putting two `ListView`s inside a `ScrollView` seems redundant.

Answer (score 2):

Your inner `ListView` widgets are capturing the scroll event but don't contain enough items to scroll themselves, and when you're using a `SingleChildScrollView` an inner `ListView` is redundant anyway. I'd recommend changing them to `Column`:

```dart
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('Second Page'),
  ),
  body: Center(
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: itemsDishes,
          ),
          Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: itemsDrinks,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: @CristianF.Bustos You didn't replace the `ListView` like I said, you just put `Columns` inside them.

Answer (score 1):

You may just not have enough items on your screen!

You can also set `physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),` on your `SingleChildScrollView`.

Comment: It doesn't work! Also each listing has more than 4 items